# Active, wifi enabled USB key

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, usb, usb-flash-drive

I'm looking for a system-on-chip which:

- looks like a USB key
- it is powered through USB
- it supports vanilla Linux
- it has wifi connectivity

Is it there such a thing?

Comment: So you want USB Memmory stick that will power on your system when it is plugged in, and can act as Wi-Fi antenna? or am i missing something here.

Comment: Something like this? http://www.amazon.co.uk/SainSmart-SS808-PC-On-A-Stick-Computer-Processor/dp/B009EMFAO6

Comment: Is linux must be on chip or on PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest Mk802 from allwinner or similar device. Speciffically for the A10 there is ubuntu port: https://www.miniand.com/forums/forums/2/topics/1

Answer (score 0):

[Russian one](http://virt2real.ru).

You can install Linux on Android micro-PCs such as [Minix](http://linux-sunxi.org/MinixX10).